# Prolog - Pattern matching : complex expression linked by operator

Tags: prolog, pattern-matching, extract, operator-keyword

I am new in prolog and I would like to know if there a way to replace part of a element describe like that :

```
S = ( tab/field = 2 ), (X/Y=V)=S.
S = ( +field > 2 ), (+Y>V)=S.
```

With the following examples, I would like to replace part of the expression (the X and Y part) but keep the operator, like that :

```
( replacedValue = 2)
( replacedValue > 2)
```

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
?- S = (tab/field = 2), display(S), S =.. [Op, L, R], Result =.. [Op, replaced, R].
=(/(tab,field),2)
S =  (tab/field=2),
Op =  (=),
L = tab/field,
R = 2,
Result =  (replaced=2).

?- S = (+field > 2), display(S), S =.. [Op, L, R], Result =.. [Op, replaced, R].
>(+(field),2)
S =  (+field>2),
Op =  (>),
L = +field,
R = 2,
Result =  (replaced>2).
```

Comment: thanks : The given example in the docs ( http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=(%3D..)/2 ) didn't show the case of a compound variable